# How does one make an equality constraint on a class function?

Tags: haskell, type-families

Given

```hs
class ProblemC c where
  data ProblemData c :: * -> *
  embedC :: (ProblemData c x ~ x) => x -> c x

data TestThing a f
  = TestA a
  | TestB f
  deriving Functor

instance (ProblemData (TestThing a) x ~ a) => ProblemC (TestThing a) where
  data ProblemData (TestThing a) b = TestData a
  embedC = TestA
```

How do I get something that type checks?

Essentially I want a class that will embed (and extract, not included in example code) some parameterized type.

Comment: `ProblemData c x ~ x` will *never* be true, because `ProblemData c` is declared to be `data`, which always defines a new data type. I'm afraid I don't understand what the goal of this typeclass is. Can you explain a bit more, in English, what your requirements are?

Comment: Oh, thanks! You've pointed me in the right direction. I should be using `type` rather than `data` in the class definition

Comment: Glad I could help! You might also look into the [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3) package, which does similar things to what it looks like you're trying to do. In particular, I think your `embedC` function is just the [`MonoPointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoPointed) typeclass.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the question from Silvio I figured it out. What I wanted:

```hs
class ProblemC c where
  type ProblemData c
  embedC :: ProblemData c -> c (ProblemData c)

data TestThing a f
  = TestA a
  | TestB f
  deriving Functor

instance ProblemC (TestThing a) where
  type ProblemData (TestThing a) = a
  embedC = TestA
```